# Nginx: How to connect backend port in react dockerized image

Tags: docker, nginx

I have a react application. So I used below Dockerfile to build docker image

```
    # pull official base image
FROM node:12.13.0-alpine AS build
# STAGE 1


WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN yarn  install

COPY . /app

RUN yarn build

# STAGE 2

FROM nginx:stable-alpine

COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And Backend is running on x.x.x.x:4004.
Now I am running my react app.
Server calls are not working it showing 404.
How can I connect to backend server to Nginx server. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What URL do you use to call the backend from your react app?

Comment: http:xx.xxx.xxx.xx:4004  I am using this type of URL. This is also docker image running on 4004 port.

Comment: I think it might be CORS related since you're loading the react app from a different site than your API is on. Can you check if your API accepts all origins?

Answer (score 0):

Query the docker container for the IP address`docker inspect (containerNameOrId)`

In your dockerfile you need to expose the ports for both containers to communicate with each other.

for example,
`EXPOSE 80/tcp`

If it was outside of docker then you need to publish the port. When starting the container with

`docker run -p 80:80 (other parameters)`

the above example has mapped port 80 of the container port to the host port 80

Check from the docker container hosts, you can ping your nginx server, and from nginx server to the docker container hosts. if you cant then check the firewall settings.

Comment: Actually React app  and Backend server both are running on docker by using docker run command. And it worked before using nginx server why because i gave proxy in  react application of package.json file